# Eclipse Public License v1.0

Tags: eclipse

I would like to use a code which is under EPL v.1 license in a commercial project. As I know I can do so, but the problem is that I need to make some changes in this code.

Thus, I have two questions:

1. Can I change the EPL code and then use it in a commercial project without any restrictions.
2. If I am allowed do so, should I remove copyright notes in the files I made changes or may be I should add some additional notes.

Answer (score 2):

Read Paragraph 4 in the [official licence text](http://opensource.org/licenses/EPL-1.0).

You may use it for commercial products, but it must not create any liability on other (previous open source) contributors. In particular, you're responsible on your own if any problems occur.